# Error Comparing text of editText

Tags: android, arraylist, compare, android-edittext

This code try to catch the string of a EditText and compare it with a string of a array.
The code don't have errors, but when I clic the button nothing happens (even the toast is no shown), what i'm doing wrong?
THANKS

This is te array of arrays.
list.xml

```
<resources>
        <string-array name="array1">
            <item name="number">1</item>
            <item name="name">first</item>
        </string-array>
        <string-array name="array2">
            <item name="number">2</item>
            <item name="name">second</item>
        </string-array>

    <array name="list">
        <item>@array/array1</item>
        <item>@array/array2</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

This is the code of the main xml file
main.xml

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/etname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone" >

<Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="searchArray"
            android:text="@string/search" />
```

SearchArray

```
public void searchArray(View view){
        Resources res = getResources();
        TypedArray ta = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.list);
        int n = ta.length();
        String[][] array = new String[n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int id = ta.getResourceId(i, 0);
            if (id > 0) {
                array[i] = res.getStringArray(id);
            } else {
                // something wrong with the XML
            }
        }
        ta.recycle(); 

        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etname);
        String stringname = name.getText().toString();

        if (stringname != null){
            for (int cont = 0; cont < n; ++cont) {
                if (!(array[cont][1].equals(stringname))){
                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), array[cont][1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast2.show();
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WRONG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Good observation by Szymon below. I also noticed that you're comparing with a TextView and not an EditText at all, despite what you said in your question.

Comment: It isn't the error, I change it and it isn't work

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're comparing from index 1, not 0. Change the code

```
 for (int cont = 0; cont < n; ++cont)
```

To

```
for (int cont = 0; cont < n; cont++)
```

Comment: I think that the error is in the for, but is no for that, because it should show the toast "WRONG", but nothing happen

Comment: What is the value of `n`?

Comment: Yes, I know, but what is the value when you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
public void searchArray(View view){
        Resources res = getResources();
        TypedArray ta = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.list);
        int n = ta.length();
        String[][] array = new String[n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int id = ta.getResourceId(i, 0);
            if (id > 0) {
                array[i] = res.getStringArray(id);
                System.out.println(res.getStringArray(id));
            } else {
                // something wrong with the XML
            }
        }
        ta.recycle(); 

        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);// I changed TextView to EditText
        String stringname = name.getText().toString();

        if (stringname != null){
            for (int cont = 0; cont < n; ++cont) {
                System.out.println(array[cont][1]+" "+stringname);
                if ((array[cont][1].equals(stringname))){//Edit Here, If it matches, Show Toast
                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), array[cont][1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast2.show();
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WRONG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Hope this help you.